# How to transfer url in email template

Tags: email-template

I embeded an url in email template, like this:

```
http://www.abc.com?param1={!Account.Name}
```

Sometime the account name would contain a blank, such as Allen li. Then we will get an url like this: 
`http://www.abc.com?param1=Allen li`

That's a problem because the link will be divided. I don't want fix this by apex code. Is there a solution about this?

Comment: Have you tried using the `SUBSTITUTE` expression and replace `' '` whitespace with `%20` which is URL encoded value for whitespace?

Comment: We can't use formula function in email template.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [URLENCODE](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_variables_functions.htm) formula function.

> Encodes text and merge field values for use in URLs by replacing characters that are illegal in URLs, such as blank spaces, with the code that represent those characters as defined in RFC 3986, Uniform Resource Identifier (URI): Generic Syntax. For example, blank spaces are replaced with %20, and exclamation points are replaced with %21.
>
> {!URLENCODE(text)} and replace text with the merge field or text string that you want to encode.

i've just tested this with a Text based Email Template and it seems to work just fine. The following...

```
http://www.abc.com?param1={!URLENCODE(Account.Name)}
```

Gives...

```
http://www.abc.com?param1=Burlington+Textiles+Corp+of+America
```

Comment: Your welcome, go Visualforce functions! :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can create formula field where you will replace all unwanted characters and build link