# HTML Email Template URL Base64 Encode

Tags: email, email-template, parameters, base64, url-encode

Based in question [HTML Email Template URL Encode](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/50801/html-email-template-url-encode)

That it exposes the problem like:

```
<a href="http://example.com/?region={!URLENCODE(Contact.Region__c)}">Click me</a>
```

I am trying to encode a parameter in base64 string in a email template

```
<a href="http://example.com/?region={!BASE64ENCODE(Contact.Region__c)}">Click me</a>
```

I try to figure out how to do this with the [documentation of page variable functions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_variables_functions.htm), but it seems that BASE64ENCODE or similar is not defined.

Since it is a email template, I don't have access to javascript to encode a text in base64 for a string template, and it is in a user email template defined, without APEX, so how properly encode in base64 a string in a email template?

Comment: What kind of template are you trying to use? HTML? Plain Text? Visualforce?

Comment: It is a HTML template loaded in Salesforce (after payment page hook where the page variable functions are available) with a button. No Visualforce.